# pasar datos de componente a un servio en angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hola amigos tengo una duda es posible enviar datos a servicio desde un componente y luego desde el servicio enviarlos a otro componente.
en este código tengo errores pero en si lo que quisiera es pasar el array datos que esta en el primer componente al servicio y luego que el  servicio me lo envié al componente 2, y de ante mano gracias por la ayuda

componente 1

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {DatoscompraService} from './../datoscompra.service'



@Component({
  selector: 'app-carteras',
  templateUrl: './carteras.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carteras.component.css']
})
export class CarterasComponent implements OnInit {
  datos:any = [
    {
      producto:'Cartera 1',
      cantidad: 3,
      precio:200
    },
    {
      producto:'Cartera 2',
      cantidad: 1,
      precio:500
    },
  ];

  constructor(private servicio:DatoscompraService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public enviar(){
    return this.datos;
  }

}
```

servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatoscompraService {

 datoss:any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  public enviarPara(){

  }




}
```

componente 2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import {DatoscompraService} from './../datoscompra.service'




@Component({
  selector: 'app-cabecera',
  templateUrl: './cabecera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cabecera.component.css']
})
export class CabeceraComponent implements OnInit {

  datos:any[] = [];

  constructor(private servicio:DatoscompraService){
    this.datos = servicio.enviarPara();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si los componentes no son padre e hijo, la forma de pasar datos entre ellos es a través de servicios. te dejo una posible solución. En el servicio tienes que tener un `set` y un `get`. El `set` es para 'guardar' lo que envíes del componente 1 en el servicio y el `get` para enviarlos a cualquier otro componente, en este caso al componente 2

```
setArray(array: any) {
  this.arrayDelService = array;
}

getArray() {
  return this.arrayDelService;
}
```

En el componente 1 crea un método que reciba ese array para luego llamarlo desde el `ngOnInit`

```
sendArray(datos) {
  this._service.setArray(datos);
}
```

En el componente 2 crear una variable que pintará lo que el servicio le envía. Esto lo haces desde el `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.arrayDesdeService = this._service.getArray();
}
```

Y por último, en el html del componente 2 pintas el array con un `*ngFor`

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of arrayDesdeService">
  <li>{{item.producto}}</li>
  <li>{{item.cantidad}}</li>
  <li>{{item.precio}}</li>
</ul>
```

Como es un poco lioso, lo puedes ver funcionando [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zy4abn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcomp1%2Fcomp1.component.html)

Saludos

Comment: gracias amigo si me sirvio

Comment: hola Eugeni gracias por tu repuesta, pero tengo un problema el cual no entiendo, he colocado el código exactamente como tu lo colocaste en https://stackblitz.com/  pero no me funciona, pero lo que parece raro es que le hecho unas modificaciones pero en mi proyecto de angular no funciona mientras que en https://stackblitz.com/ en el código que tu hiciste si funciona, osea, reemplazo el código con las modificaciones que le hecho y funciona en https://stackblitz.com/ de manera perfecta, pero en mi proyecto de angular no y eso es lo que no entiendo. Estaré a atento a tu respuesta gracias.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6qaz4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarteras%2Fcarteras.component.ts   aquí si funciona pero en mi proyecto de angular no funciona es angular 6

Comment: creo que veo el problema es que obligatoria-mente se debe colocar <comp1></comp1>
<comp2></comp2>  en      app.component.html, como se hace si solo quiero colocar <comp2></comp2> y el otro lo quiero colocar en una pestaña osea que no sea fijo si no que con <router-outlet></router-outlet> con una ruta acceda a el, he estado tratando  de colocarlo con <router-outlet></router-outlet> y me presenta error, también si coloco otro componente en el mismo app.component.html también presenta error se borra todo no muestra el contenido.

Comment: Buenas, obligatoriamente hay que colocar comp1?? según tu pregunta inicial si porque él enviará los datos al service, pero si lo que quieres es usar un router, en tu router tendrás que incluir algo así `{path: 'comp1', component: Comp1Component}` donde comp1 es como lo llamarás en la barra de direcciones (http://localhost:4200/#/comp1) y Comp1Component el nombre del componente